# Run command after CTRL+C on watch command

Tags: bash, watch, exit-code

I’m running a watch command in a bash script. I want the script to run a command after I stop the watch command (Ctrl+c). Anything I put after the watch command in the script does not execute

Answer (score 5):

In a Bash script, when you press Ctrl+C, the system sends the process the *SIGINT* signal, which if it is not handled, **the default behavior of the process that receives it is to terminate the execution**.

If what you want to do is do something when the user presses Ctrl+C, you would want to **trap** the signal.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Function that will get executed when the user presses Ctrl+C
function handler(){
    echo "Processing the Ctrl+C"
}

# Assign the handler function to the SIGINT signal
trap handler SIGINT

watch ls -l
```

Comment: When I run this and click Ctrl+c it should print “Processing the Ctrl+c” but I am getting no output

Comment: @Ryan Put the command you want to run after Ctrl+C press in the handler() function, you can simply replace `echo "Processing the Ctrl+C"` with your command.

Comment: Very well explained and straight to the point. +1